# How to handle fragments backstack changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some king of header in my activity, which says what kind of fragment is opened now. It's ok, when I'm just replacing one fragment by another, but I have a problem with handling backstack changes in `onBackPressed`. That's a part of my code in `onBackPressed` method:

```
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
```

in first row, `fragment=FormFragment{41f01d58 #3 id=0x7f05005f}`, and after calling `popBackStack` I have `fragment=FormFragment{41f01d58 #3 id=0x7f05005f}` again (but it should be another fragment, even not `FormFragment` instance).

Is there any way how to find out what fragment is popped from backstack after calling `popBackStack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, usually you don't have to pop the fragment back stack yourself. If your activity is a `FragmentActivity`, its default `onBackPressed()` will do the work for you.

To update your header when the fragment is popped from the back stack, put the header update code in the fragment's `onResume()`.